# Why can't I add an object to a plist

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add an object to a plist whenever the user hits the star. I'm having problems displaying the objects in another table view, and I strongly suspect the promblem is in this method.

```
-(IBAction)favbutton
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Favorites" ofType:@"plist"];

    // Build the array from the plist  ------>>>

    NSDictionary *favs = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

    favMutArray = [favs objectForKey:@"Name"];

    [favMutArray addObject:stateName];

    [favMutArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSLog(@"StateButtonFinished");
}
```

The button is conntected(from seeing NSLog), stateName is an NSString, and Favorites.plist contains am root with Name, Phone, Fax, and Address arrays. If you need more information I can provide it. Thank you!

Comment: An app's resource bundle is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting the `plist` via `NSBundle` then it's part of the app bundle and that cannot be written to.

You will need to copy the `plist` to the app's document folder and update it from there, much like developers have to do with databases that are "seeded" from a copy held in the app bundle.